# type_synonym vs consts in Isabelle definition

Tags: isabelle

I have the two following expressions in isabelle:

```
consts drives ::"(Person × Car) set"

type_synonym drives="(Person × Car) set"
```

How they are different in terms of their semantics?

I think that **type_synonym** is just a brief name for the type specified in front of it. right?

But what **const** is for? (Isabelle tutorial document --page 119-- says: "This is Isabelle’s way of declaring a constant without defining it." But in what sense above expression can be a constant?!!)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, **type_synonym** is just the a synonym for the type specified, it does not introduce any new type.

**consts** just states you will define a new constant of the given type, without actually specifying how it is defined. (Note that since in Isabelle/HOL every type is inhabit, nothing has to be proved that such a constant can even exist). Afterwards you can define other functions, definitions, etc. which may already use the newly defined constant (`drives` in your example, and `drives_c` in my example below). At some point you can then actually provide the definition of the constant via **defs**.

```
type_synonym drives_t = "(int * nat) set"

consts drives_c :: "(int * nat) set"

(* test_drives already used drives_c *)
definition test_drives :: "int => bool" where 
   "test_drives x == (x, 5) : drives_c"

(* here, you actually define drives_c *)
defs drives_c_def: "drives_c == {(3,2), (7,5)}"
```

However, standard definitions can more directly be performed via **definition**.

```
definition drives_c :: drives_t where
  "drives_c == {(3,2), (7,5)}"
```

Hope this helps,
René

Comment: Thanks for your response and excuse me for the following naive question: when it is written "(x, 5) : drives_c" what does the colon between (x,5) and drives_c indicate? --considering that the drive_c is not a type!

Comment: The colon `:` ist just ASCII-syntax for set-membership, so `∈`.

Comment: The colon ":" is the ASCII representation of the member operation on sets, and "drives_c" is some set of pairs of integers and natural number. The double colon "::" is used to constrain the type of a value.