# Factoring out a lemma premise as a definition causes failure in proof method (auto) application in isabelle

Tags: isabelle, isar

I have the following code in Isabelle:

```
typedecl Person
consts age :: "Person ⇒ int" 

lemma "⟦(∀p::Person. age p > 20);p ∈ Person⟧⟹ age p > 20"
apply (auto)
done
```

The *auto* proof method works fine and proves the lemma! when I want to factor out the first part of the premise in the lemma as a definition C1 as bellow:

```
definition C1::bool where "C1 ≡ (∀p::Person. age p > 20)"
```

The *auto* methods fails to prove in the following code:

```
lemma "⟦C1;p ∈ Person⟧⟹ age p > 20"
apply (auto)
done
```

why this happens? If I am doing wrong in the way of factoring out the first assumption ---I am doing this to organize the assumption to look neat and structured-- what is the best way to do this that does not affect the prove methods (auto) functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to actually add some value, I show how to use `declare` to add `C1_def` as a `simp` rule. I then give you some unrequested pointers about your `lemma`, and then I give you some unasked for pointers about Stackoverflow etiquette (from my viewpoint).

## Declaring a definition as a simp rule

As Alexander pointed out, a `definition` is not automatically added as a `simp` rule.

You can declare it as a `simp` rule like this:

```
declare C1_def [simp add]
```

The use of simp rules by the automatic proof methods `auto`, `simp`, `fastforce`, etc. can cause bad looping, or expand formulas in ways that you don't want the formulas expanded, so after adding it, you can remove it as a `simp` rule like this:

```
declare C1_def [simp del]
```

## Comments on your lemma

It could be that the formula in your lemma is exactly what you want, but your notation, in my opinion, is a potential source of confusion. In particular, that you're using `Person` as both the name of a type and a set variable. I make these comments without asking for clarification.

For myself, my question was, "How is it that `p ∈ Person` is not giving an error, because `Person` there is a set, where `Person` in `typedecl Person` is not a set.

One way to get more information is with `declare [[show_types, show_consts]]`.

To answer my question, I did the following (converting symbols for browser portability), and I show some of what I saw in the output panel:

```
declare [[show_types, show_consts]]
lemma "[|(!p::Person. age p > 20); p ∈ Person|] ==> (age p > 20)"
oops
(*OUTPUT:
  variables:
    Person :: Person set
    p :: Person *)
```

It shows me that `Person` is a free variable. As to `p`, it's a bound variable in `(!p::Person. age p > 20)`, but it's free in the rest of the lemma, so your hypothesis includes the formula that every `p` of type `Person` is in every set of type `Person set`.

It could be that's what you want, but in this case, it makes no difference because your lemma is basically of the form `A and B implies A`.

## You need to accept an answer to an answered SO question

Before I disappear in about 2 hours, for the `isabelle` tag, I again do my beloved duty as the SO etiquette police.

You've asked three questions. In particular, there is this one:

- [type_synonym vs consts in Isabelle definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26781778/type-synonym-vs-consts-in-isabelle-definition)

It's a straightforward question, and it's given a straightforward answer. You need to accept it as an answer. Otherwise,

- when people click on the "unanswered" tab for the "isabelle" tag, it might show up as unanswered, when it has been unanswered,
- you're not showing proper appreciation, to the extent you should, for the answer that was given.

In the case of the question I linked to, you got an answer from one of the Isbelle/HOL experts (unlike me). It takes a significant amount of time for a person to type in an answer like that. It's not extraordinarily long, but then it's not a one-liner either.

Comment: Thanks user3317019, I was new in this website and was not aware of the accept-answer mechanism. I did set the answered tag in the mentioned questions to be an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 1):

The construct `definition` serves as a way to abstract away implementation details. One of its use is to prove some properties of the associated term and then rely on the properties instead of the term declaration itself. Therefore the simplification rules for the defined terms are not added automatically to the `simpset`. The rules are still available with the name of the term with a suffix `_def` and can be used explicitly:

```
lemma "⟦C1; p ∈ Person⟧ ⟹ age p > 20"
  apply (auto simp add: C1_def)
done
```